# Java XML Writing

Tags: java, xml, dom

I scraped together some code from sources on the internet. I just need something that appends to the end of an XML file.

When I use this code, it formats the new entry properly but the xml that was there before gets spaced out further too. I want it to add to the end without touching anything that was there before. Without `transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount","2")`, it just outputs everything new to one line.

```
package xml;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

public class Writer {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse("input.xml");
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

        Element newUser = document.createElement("user");

        Element name = document.createElement("name");
        name.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test_name"));
        newUser.appendChild(name);

        Element username = document.createElement("username");
        username.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test_username"));
        newUser.appendChild(username);
        
        Element email = document.createElement("email");
        email.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test_email"));
        newUser.appendChild(email);
        
        Element password = document.createElement("password");
        password.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test_password"));
        newUser.appendChild(password);

        root.appendChild(newUser);

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount","2");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult("input.xml");
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        
    }
}
```

XML before code runs

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<Test>

   <user>
      <name>alpha</name>
      <username>alpha1</username>
      <email>alpha@gmail.com</email>
      <password>a</password>
   </user>
   
   <user>
      <name>beta</name>
      <username>beta1</username>
      <email>beta@gmail.com</email>
      <password>b</password>
   </user>
   
   <user>
      <name>omega</name>
      <username>omega1</username>
      <email>omega@gmail.com</email>
      <password>w</password>
   </user>

</Test>
```

XML after code runs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Test>
     
  <user>
          
    <name>alpha</name>
          
    <username>alpha1</username>
          
    <email>alpha@gmail.com</email>
          
    <password>a</password>
       
  </user>
     
   
  <user>
          
    <name>beta</name>
          
    <username>beta1</username>
          
    <email>beta@gmail.com</email>
          
    <password>b</password>
       
  </user>
     
   
  <user>
          
    <name>omega</name>
          
    <username>omega1</username>
          
    <email>omega@gmail.com</email>
          
    <password>w</password>
       
  </user>
  
  <user>
    <name>test_name</name>
    <username>test_username</username>
    <email>test_email</email>
    <password>test_password</password>
  </user>
</Test>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed that when I run your code with java 11 I get the same result as you, but if I change to java 8 than I get the following result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Test>

   <user>
      <name>alpha</name>
      <username>alpha1</username>
      <email>alpha@gmail.com</email>
      <password>a</password>
   </user>
   
   <user>
      <name>beta</name>
      <username>beta1</username>
      <email>beta@gmail.com</email>
      <password>b</password>
   </user>
   
   <user>
      <name>omega</name>
      <username>omega1</username>
      <email>omega@gmail.com</email>
      <password>w</password>
   </user>

<user>
    <name>test_name</name>
    <username>test_username</username>
    <email>test_email</email>
    <password>test_password</password>
  </user>
</Test>
```

(yes, the indentation exactly is like this)

So this looks like a bug in java / the jdk .. I know ... not a real answer but definitely interesting.

Comment: That's very interesting

Comment: @Vikings1028 maybe its difference between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK .. I think that my Java 11 is OpenJDK and my Java 8 is Oracle JDK ... but I'm not sure if I remember this correctly and I have no idea how to find out.

Comment: If you are using OpenJDK https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8250879?attachmentViewMode=list and 
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223291 maybe somehow "answer" your question